# What does `cat file | ssh host 'cat - >file'` do?

Tags: bash, scripts, ssh, remote, pipe

this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() {
    echo "deploy-nginx.sh --production|--staging"
}

case "$1" in
    --staging) NGINX_CONF="conf/nginx-staging"; HOST="staging" ;;
    --production) NGINX_CONF="conf/nginx-production"; HOST="production" ;;
    *) usage; exit 2;
esac

cat "$NGINX_CONF" | ssh -F conf/ssh_config "$HOST" '
    cat - > /tmp/ironscales
    sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available//tmp/myapp{,-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}
    sudo mv /tmp/myapp /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp
    sudo service nginx reload
'
```

I understand the usage function, and the case switch

what I don't understand at all, is the part following cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part following `cat "$NGINX_CONF"` serves to copy the file from the `$NGINX_CONF` variable to the remote machine using `ssh` and perform other actions.

- `cat "$NGINX_CONF" | ssh` opens the file and pipes it to the `ssh` process, a less efficient way of letting the shell do the same with

  ```
  <"$NGINX_CONF" ssh
  ```

  The part in single quotes holds the command(s) to run on the remote machine. `ssh` forwards its input (i.e. the file content) to this command.
- `cat - > /tmp/ironscales` redirects `cat`’s (= `ssh`’s) standard input (`-`) to the specified file

Comment: Odd but simple way to do it. rsync or scp would be clearer and arguably easier

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Well, if you want to run (other) commands on the remote machine this is the way with one ssh connection only – it was new to me as well, but it’s not that bad IMO.